# Combination of Two Answers Is The Correct Answer

Tags: discussion, answers

I recently asked a question on SO to which the combination of two separate answers should be the accepted answer, however each answer by itself is not completely really correct.  I edited my original question to make it a little more specific to the scenario that was causing me a problem.  Once I did this and started testing out users suggestions I discovered that a combination of answers actually solves the issue at hand.  Is there any way that this is supposed to be handled to provide an accepted answer?

Comment: Leave a comment for the authors or post your complete solution as an answer giving credt to the original answers

Comment: You can post your own answer to the question and attribute the two authors who led to your solution. It is common practice, when your answer is basically just quoting someone else, to mark the answer as "Community Wiki".

Comment: @rene looks like I accidentally duped this, didn't see that answer before.

Comment: @JNYRanger, just to be clear, if your answer contains a significant amount of your own work/research, then it would be appropriate to *not* mark it Community Wiki - just be sure to acknowledge the contributions of others in your research efforts. (There's no requirement - most people just feel more comfortable marking the post CW when using a substantial amount of someone else's work.)

Comment: Your question looked fine to me, but if there's a reason that it's confusing and would cause people to post the wrong answer you might want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 14):

Well the best thing to do is probably to write your own answer telling how did you combine both answers (telling you took it from Mr.X and Mr.Y). Make sure to include the relevant information from the answers in your answer to make it complete though. You can accept your own answer after a few days.

Making another answer is better because it will contain the missing information as how to combine the information from the two other answer and thus helping users finding this question in the future. Also, accepting only one of the two answer could mislead other users.

Make sure to upvote the two answers that were useful to you.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I'm going to do.  They've already been upvoted, so I'll mention them in my combined answer.  I just wanted to make sure credit is given to those that deserved it since this is a community site.